# What sequence does $\frac{1}{1-s-s^4}$ generate?

Tags: generating-functions

When attempting to find an easy answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312695/)

> What is the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in the power series expansion of $\dfrac 1{1-x-x^4}$?

I'd think of $\frac{1}{1-x-x^4}$ as of a generating function. I did some series expansion on [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B-%28-1+%2B+x+%2B+x%5E4%29%5E%28-1%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+19%7D%5D) and 'googled' the sequence on [oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+7%2C+10%2C+14%2C+19%2C+26%2C+36%2C+50%2C+69%2C+95%2C+131%2C+181&language=english&go=Search). It's http://oeis.org/A003269 .
$$a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-4)\text{ with }a(0) = 0, a(1) = a(2) = a(3) = 1.$$

So the **question** is: why does this happen? I.e. I need some explanation why is $\dfrac{1}{1-s-s^4}$ the generating function for the sequence above.

Comment: Write $\frac{1}{1 - x - x^4}$ as a power series, then clear the denominator.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-s-s^4}=\frac{1}{1-(s(s^3+1))}=\sum_{n\ge 0}s^n(s^3+1)^n$

Comment: Note your indices are off by $1$, as explained in my answer. $\frac{1}{1-x-x^4}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$, not $0+x+x^2+\cdots$ as your indices suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, consider a generating function 
$$ f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials.
Write $Q(x) = q_0 + q_1 x + \ldots + q_d x^d$.  Thus $P(x) = f(x) Q(x)$.  If 
$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots$, then the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x) Q(x)$ is
$a_{n-d} q_d + \ldots +a_{n} q_0$, so if $n$ is greater than the degree of $P(x)$, this must be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a(n)$ are coefficients of a power series $f(x)=\sum a(n)x^n$, then multiplying by $x^k$ gives $$x^kf(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^{n+k}=\sum_{n=-k}^\infty a(n-k)x^n$$
So if you start with

- $a(n)=a(n-1)+a(n-4)$,
- defining $a(n)$ to be $0$ for negative $n$

then the recurrence almost still holds for small $n$ when $a(0)=0$ and $a(1)=a(2)=a(3)=1$. The recurrence fails for $n=1$ though. This tells us  $$\sum_{n=-4,n\neq1}^\infty a(n)x^n=\sum_{n=-4,n\neq1}^\infty a(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n=-4,n\neq1}^\infty a(n-4)x^n$$ 
$$\implies \sum_{n=-4}^\infty a(n)x^n-x=\sum_{n=-4}^\infty a(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n=-4}^\infty a(n-4)x^n$$ 
$$\implies f(x)-xf(x)-x^4f(x)=x$$ which implies $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^4}$ for $x$ in the interval of convergence. Since power series for rational functions like this are unique, if you now start with the rational function $\frac{x}{1-x-x^4}$, it must have this sequence $a(n)$ as its power series coefficients.

Your function is this one divided by $x$, so indices all shift by $1$. You have the right recurrence for $\frac{1}{1-x-x^4}$, but note that your indices are off. For instance, you have $a(0)=0$, but for $\frac{1}{1-x-x^4}$, the constant term is clearly $1$.